# python intersection of utf-8 list and utf-8 string

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii, intersection

I made this code work when I use list with `ASCII` letters and `ASCII` strings, but I couldn't make this work.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
asa = ["ā","ē","ī","ō","ū","ǖ","Ā","Ē","Ī","Ō","Ū","Ǖ",
"á","é","í","ó","ú","ǘ","Á","É","Í","Ó","Ú","Ǘ",
"ǎ","ě","ǐ","ǒ","ǔ","ǚ","Ǎ","Ě","Ǐ","Ǒ","Ǔ","Ǚ",
"à","è","ì","ò","ù","ǜ","À","È","Ì","Ò","Ù","Ǜ"]
[x.decode('utf-8') for x in asa]
print list(set(asa) & set("ō"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your character within a list, because strings are iterable objects and your unicode character is contain 2 byte string thus python assumes "ō" as `\xc5` and `\x8d`.
:

```
>>> list("ō")
['\xc5', '\x8d']
>>> print list(set(asa) & set(["ō"]))
['\xc5\x8d']
>>> print list(set(asa) & set(["ō"]))[0]
ō
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first set contains elements of the form `"ō".decode('utf-8')` (type `unicode`), equivalent to `u"ō"`.

The second set contains byte strings like `"ō"` (type `str`), so they don't compare equal and you get no intersections.

Medidate:

```
>>> 'a' == u'a'
True
>>> 'ō' == u'ō'
__main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False
>>> list('ō')
['\xc5', '\x8d']
>>> list(u'ō')
[u'\u014d']
```